# Check if column exists on linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I'm currently working on a project in which I need to check if data exists on a linked server in SQL Server. The method down below is what I use now, but it's way too slow.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.HasEBoekhoudenBybtwnr
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.HasEBoekhoudenBybtwnr(@btwnr varchar(255))
AS
IF (EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 AbBedrijf FROM [Server].[database].[dbo].[table] WHERE abOBNummer = @btwnr))
    SELECT 1
ELSE  
   SELECT 0
GO
```

I tried to use sp_executesql and open sql but I don't how to use it with `if exists`. Can anyone help me improve this method?

Comment: u need to check column or table or both

Comment: Only the column the table itself is pretty big

Comment: can u check once .

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic query as below:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR (500)
SET @sql = '
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM [server].database.dbo.'+ @btwnr + ')
    SELECT 1
ELSE
    SELECT 0 '

EXEC(@sql)
```

As per your updated question, you can directly compare variable value to column value. Dynamic query not needed.

Comment: There is no table called btwnr, it's a value which resides in a table

Comment: I mean to say, This '@btwnr' is a variable that you have and if you are passing table name in it then you have to use dynamic query for the if exists selection and if column value then you can directly do at as you are doing now. You should not get any issue if rest of things are all right.

Answer (score 0):

I now have modified the procedure by using sp_executesql but it made no difference in performance or what so ever. So I think it's best to stick to my original procedure and except that it is not as fast as I would like.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.HasEBoekhoudenBybtwnr
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.HasEBoekhoudenBybtwnr(@btwnr varchar(255))
AS
EXEC sp_executesql N'
IF (EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 AbBedrijf FROM [Server].[database].[dbo].[table] WHERE abOBNummer = @btw))
    SELECT 1
ELSE
    SELECT 0 ',
N'@btw varchar(255)',
@btw = @btwnr
GO
```

I would still thank everyone for their input on this issue